# Consequtive integers covered by $n$ arithmetic progressions

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, dynamical-systems

Suppose there are $n$ terms of an arithmetic progression of the form

$$(2i+1)k + x_i, ~~~~ i = 1,\ldots,n, ~~~~ k \geq 0,$$

for varying initial integer terms $x_i \geq 0$.

The problem is to cover $m(n)$—the maximum possible number of consecutive integers starting with $1$ (the number is covered, if it belongs to at least one of these progressions).

For example, is it true that
$$m(n) \approx \operatorname*{LCM}\limits_{i=1,\,\ldots\,,\,n}(\{2i+1\}) \text{?}$$

Numerical simulations seem to suggest $m(n) \approx Cn$.

Comment: Is i supposed to be the index for the progressions or the index for the sequence of progressions? I'm trying make sense of (2i+1)k+x_i, as i varies.